# Why are the chapters named after other works?

Tags: school-rumble

Just noticed that some (if not all) of the chapter titles are named after another movie or book. There is

- Chapter 005. [Enter the Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_the_Dragon)
- Chapter 031. [God Father](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather)
- Chapter 037. [Mission Impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission:_Impossible_(film_series))
- Chapter 041. [Die Hard II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Hard_2)
- or Chapter 059. [Groundhog Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day_(film))

just to name a few.

And then I take a look at Wikipedia entry about [list of School Rumble chapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_School_Rumble_chapters) and pick some random chapter and always find another work, film, series, or novel with the same title. Even side stories like

- Side stories 15. [Once Upon a Time in Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_Mexico)
- Side stories 25. [Monsters Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsters,_Inc.)
- Side stories 54. [Ocean's Eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean%27s_Eleven)

are named after another works.

So I tried to see [list of School Rumble episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_School_Rumble_episodes), and it looks like only the manga chapters are named after other works.

Some titles are related to the story somehow, but some titles seem a little bit random. Why do these chapters use other works' titles? Has there been any word from the author about this? Are all chapters named after other works' titles?